# Data Loss Prevention finds superfluous entities when masking email

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I am calling the DLP API to mask person names and email addresses in text, using the following request:

**Request**

```
{
  "item": {
    "value": "Eleanor Rigby\nPharmacist\neleanor.rigby@example.com"
  },
  "deidentifyConfig": {
    "infoTypeTransformations": {
      "transformations": [
        {
          "infoTypes": [ { "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS" } ],
          "primitiveTransformation": {
            "characterMaskConfig": {
              "maskingCharacter": "#",
              "reverseOrder": false,
              "charactersToIgnore": [
                {
                  "charactersToSkip": ".@"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "infoTypes": [ { "name": "PERSON_NAME" } ],
          "primitiveTransformation": {
            "replaceConfig": {
              "newValue": {
                "stringValue": "(person)"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "inspectConfig": {
    "infoTypes": [ { "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS" }, { "name": "PERSON_NAME" } ]
  }
}
```

**API call**

```
curl -s \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://dlp.googleapis.com/v2/projects/$PROJECT_ID/content:deidentify \
  -d @gcp-dlp/input/text-request.json
```

**Response**

```
{
  "item": {
    "value": "(person)\nPharmacist\n(person)#######.#####@#######.###(person)"
  },
  "overview": {
    "transformedBytes": "50",
    "transformationSummaries": [
      {
        "infoType": {
          "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
        },
        "transformation": {
          "characterMaskConfig": {
            "maskingCharacter": "#",
            "charactersToIgnore": [
              {
                "charactersToSkip": ".@"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "results": [
          {
            "count": "1",
            "code": "SUCCESS"
          }
        ],
        "transformedBytes": "25"
      },
      {
        "infoType": {
          "name": "PERSON_NAME"
        },
        "transformation": {
          "replaceConfig": {
            "newValue": {
              "stringValue": "(person)"
            }
          }
        },
        "results": [
          {
            "count": "3",
            "code": "SUCCESS"
          }
        ],
        "transformedBytes": "25"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Request (text only)**

```
Eleanor Rigby
Pharmacist
eleanor.rigby@example.com
```

**Response (text only)**

```
(person)
Pharmacist
(person)#######.#####@#######.###(person)
```

The input text contains a person name and an email address. Both are detected and masked as expected. However, additional `(person)` tags are added before and after the masked email address.

This is a very simple example, but I observed this behavior in every document I processed this way.

Why is the person entity detected multiple times?

Comment: As I can see this issue [was reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173726687) by you at Google Public Issue Tracker.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I was unsure where I should post my question. I have been using GCP extensively since May and it's only very recently I found the [tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). It's not advertised much and it is not indexed by Google, is it? I've just tried [searching](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22Data+Loss+Prevention+finds+superfluous+entities+when+masking+email%22) and found only this SO post. Should I remove it **or** keep it to ensure better visibility for others?

Comment: Please keep both. You can find more details about Public Issue Tracker [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). It's not indexed, but it's a good way to report issues or request features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue [was reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173726687) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), such requests aren't indexed, but it's a good way to report issues or request new features. Please follow this case to be updated.

There's a workaround suggested by Google:

> This is a case where we have some undefined behavior when findings
> overlap. The person comes from the user's configuration to replace
> people name with person.
>
> They can [omit the overlaps](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-custom-infotypes-rules#omit_matches_on_person_name_detector_if_also_matched_by_email_address_detector).

For more information, please have a look at the documentation [Modifying infoType detectors to refine scan results](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-custom-infotypes-rules) section [Omit matches on PERSON_NAME detector if also matched by EMAIL_ADDRESS detector](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-custom-infotypes-rules#omit_matches_on_person_name_detector_if_also_matched_by_email_address_detector):

> The following JSON snippet and code in several languages illustrate
> how to indicate to Cloud DLP using an [InspectConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/InspectConfig) that it should
> only return one match in the case that matches for the `PERSON_NAME`
> detector overlap with matches for the `EMAIL_ADDRESS` detector. Doing
> this is to avoid the situation where an email address such as
> "james@example.com" matches on both the `PERSON_NAME` and `EMAIL_ADDRESS`
> detectors.
>
> ```
> ...
>     "inspectConfig":{
>       "ruleSet":[
>         {
>           "infoTypes":[
>             {
>               "name":"PERSON_NAME"
>             }
>           ],
>           "rules":[
>             {
>               "exclusionRule":{
>                 "excludeInfoTypes":{
>                   "infoTypes":[
>                     {
>                       "name":"EMAIL_ADDRESS"
>                     }
>                   ]
>                 },
>                 "matchingType": "MATCHING_TYPE_PARTIAL_MATCH"
>               }
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     } 
> ...
> ```